# wxPython MenuItem ITEM_CHECK won't uncheck

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have this (I left out code that is irrelevant):

```
class TaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):

    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        self.menu = wx.Menu()
        self.menu.chk = self.menu.Append(101, 'Show statubar', 'Show Statusbar', kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        self.menu.Check(101, True)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_tog, id=101)
        return self.menu
```

Which works, and the check on the menuitem is there.  This is a system tray icon in Linux with a right-click menu.

But when I do:

```
def on_tog(self, event):
    self.menu.Check(self.menu.chk.GetId(), False)  #Uncheck running box
```

It doesn't uncheck itself.  Even if I replace the GetID() with the actual ID of 101, it still doesn't uncheck.

What am I missing here?  There's not much documentation on changing this other than what I did, but it's not working.

Comment: It is clearly a bug of some sort, if you initially set the `Check(101,True)` even through the menu item is visibly checked and printing `IsChecked(101)` returns True, once you are in the callback function, the same `IsChecked(101)` returns False and yet the item is still, visibly checked. The opposite is true if you switch the values around. I assume that it something to do with the `TaskBarIcon` as this clearly works normally.

Comment: Right.  And even if I put `print(self.menu.chk.GetID())` in the function, it will return `101`, which is correct.  But for some reason, the Check function just won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using `AppendCheckItem`

```
self.menu.chk = self.menu.AppendCheckItem(101, 'Show statubar', 'Show Statusbar')
```

The rest of the code should work as expected.

**Update**

Here are the relevant parts of my code in their entirety

```
MENU_ITEM_ID = wx.NewId()
```

**...**

```
self.menu_item = self.menu.AppendCheckItem(MENU_ITEM_ID, "Test Menu Item")
```

**...**

```
self.menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.toggle_menuitem, id=MENU_ITEM_ID)
```

**...**

```
def toggle_menuitem(self, event):
    self.menu_item.Check(self.menu_item.IsChecked() == False) # toggle checkmark
```

**Update #2 ***

After an extended discussion in the comments, it was determined the OP had the `CreatePopupMenu` method bound to a right click event. This re-created the wx.Menu every time and thus erased any state that was assigned to the previous menu. To workaround this simply create a flag from the parent class that tracks the checkmark value and call `self.menu_item.Check(self.is_checked)` after creating the popup menu to set it to the correct state.

Comment: I'll try this out after work.  But I wonder why they have 2 methods for this that work differently...

Comment: It seems like a bug

Comment: So when you try it using just `menu.Append` like on my code, does it also not work for you?

Comment: This didn't make a difference.  It behaves the same was as the original code;  on_tog executes but the checkmark doesn't go away.

Comment: odd... I updated the post to show the exact code that I used to make it work

Comment: Do you call `CreatePopupMenu` more than once?

Comment: No, only once is it called.  EDIT: However, my toggle function is different than what you used, that might be the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138643/discussion-between-user2682863-and-dorian).

Comment: Sorry but the chat doesn't work at my office.  I'll try the def like you did it and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Ok. If `CreatePopupMenu` is bound to an event like a mouse click it will get called multiple times and create a new menu each time

Comment: You made me think when you asked if `CreatePopupMenu` was being called more than once.  I was under the impression it was called once to create the menu, but after further inspection, it is called EVERY TIME the icon is right-clicked!  So I was always setting it to true every time!  I added code to check a boolean and set it accordingly and it works now.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured